# How to use random.shuffle() on a generator? python

Tags: python, list, random, generator, shuffle

How do I use random.shuffle() on a generator without initializing a list from the generator? 
Is that even possible? if not, how else should I use `random.shuffle()` on my list?

```
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(2)
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> def yielding(ls):
...     for i in ls:
...             yield i
... 
>>> for i in random.shuffle(yielding(x)):
...     print i
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 287, in shuffle
    for i in reversed(xrange(1, len(x))):
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

Note: `random.seed()` was designed such that it returns the same output after each script run?

Comment: that does not really make sense, as the point of a generator is that you don't know what are the elements and can't access them but in an orderly fashion

Comment: because the seed is supposed to be customized so in this case: `n=2; random.seed(2)`. Sometimes the random seed could be other number.

Comment: Can't imagine any canonique method to shuffle a sequence of unknown length. And note, that `random.shuffle` shuffles *in place*.

Comment: Instead of a whole generator function, you could have used `iter(x)`.

Comment: I would suggest using a poisson distribution for a positive random look-ahead. Then (lazily or not) ignore that element from the iterated object, then repeat.

Comment: How can you put the rest of the days of your life in a random order? How can you choose a random day from the rest of your life? You'd have to know how long you're going to live, right?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In order to shuffle the sequence uniformly, `random.shuffle()` needs to know how long the input is. A generator cannot provide this; you *have* to materialize it into a list:

```
lst = list(yielding(x))
random.shuffle(lst)
for i in lst:
    print i
```

You could, instead, use `sorted()` with `random.random()` as the key:

```
for i in sorted(yielding(x), key=lambda k: random.random()):
    print(i)
```

but since this *also* produces a list, there is little point in going this route.

Demo:

```
>>> import random
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> sorted(iter(x), key=lambda k: random.random())
[9, 7, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 1, 8]
```

Comment: But this could produce duplicates?

Comment: @thefourtheye: No. It might assign two elements the same "weight" but it won't duplicate the elements themselves.

Comment: @thefourtheye: no, it just sorts the output of the `yielding(x)` generator using random values.

Comment: I would have expected `sorted` to rely on the key function being deterministic (if not, there is probably a caching mechanism (which, on second though, makes sense, given that `sorted` does not know the complexity of the key function))

Comment: The first thing `sorted()` does is storing all elements in the generator in a list, before even starting to compute the keys and sorting it.

Comment: Also, regarding the keyword part, it does make sense, as the second argument to sorted in cmp, which takes 2 arguments (although lambda x, y: random.choice([-1, 0, 1]) would work too) (or would it, or is there a risk of infinite loop?)

Comment: @njzk2: no, the key function is called only once for each value.

Comment: @njzk2: `sorted()` calls the key function exactly once on each input element, in the order they are provided.

Comment: @njzk2: the key function is used in a *decorate-sort-undecorate* style sort; sorting a list of `(keyfunc(value), None, value)` values, then extracting `value` from that again.

Comment: @njzk2: This would work in some way, but as a result you would favour certain permutations over others.

Comment: @njzk2: the `cmp` argument would normally have to be stable, but inconsistent results lead to random sorting instead of an infinite loop. I am not certain if the distribution will remain uniform in that case or if a bias is introduced, though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : isn't there a probability that the sort is never considered stable if cmp is not stable? (I just realized while writing this that no, most sorts do not re-verify elements once considered sorted.).

Comment: Quick question: Would `iter(sorted(iter(x), key=lambda k: random.random()))` first materialize the sorted list before casting it into an iterable?

Comment: @alvas: `sorted()` returns a list, always. `iter()` then produces an iterator for that list. Python doesn't alter how `sorted()` works based on what you use the returned object for.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Sorting) covers the flaws in the methods discussed by @njzk2 and the OP.  `key=random.random()` probably represents a 52-bit random number, which is probably fine.  `cmp=random.randrange(2)` not so good.

Meanwhile, I've been severely nerd-sniped trying to dig up the reference and getting derailed by other trivia on my way there.

Comment: @sh1: The default implementation returns [*multiples of 2⁻⁵³ in the range 0.0 ≤ x < 1.0*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#recipes). njzk2 was referring to the original Python 2 method of sorting, using a [`cmp()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp)' which takes 2 arguments. You can't supply `random.randrange(2)` to that ;-)

Comment: Ok, a lambda of the same effect, then.  Wikipedia discusses in detail why it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the case, if you know how much data you have ahead of time, you can index the data and compute/read from it based on a shuffled index. This amounts to: 'don't use a generator for this problem', and without specific use-cases it's hard to come up with a general method.

Alternatively... If you need to use the generator...

it depends on 'how shuffled' you want the data. Of course, like folks have pointed out, generators don't have a length, so you need to at some point evaluate the generator, which could be expensive. If you don't need perfect randomness, you can introduce a shuffle buffer:

```
from itertools import islice

import numpy as np


def shuffle(generator, buffer_size):
    while True:
        buffer = list(islice(generator, buffer_size))
        if len(buffer) == 0:
            break
        np.random.shuffle(buffer)
        for item in buffer:
            yield item


shuffled_generator = shuffle(my_generator, 256)
```

This will shuffle data in chunks of `buffer_size`, so you can avoid memory issues if that is your limiting factor. Of course, this is not a truly random shuffle, so it shouldn't be used on something that's *sorted*, but if you just need to add some randomness to your data this may be a good solution.

Comment: i took your answer and improved it a bit... see alternative below, streamed not chunked.   that way elements can migrate far beyond the buffer_size window.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to randomize the yield of a generator without temporarily saving all the elements somewhere. Luckily, this is pretty easy in Python:

```
tmp = list(yielding(x))
random.shuffle(tmp)
for i in tmp:
    print i
```

Note the call to `list()` which will read all items and put them into a list.

If you don't want to or can't store all elements, you will need to change the generator to yield in a random order.

Comment: +1 for "change the generator to yield in a random order." This is what I did when I had OP's problem. You can add an optional bool param: `def yielding(ls, randomize=False)`.

Answer (score 4):

You could sample from arbitrary yielded results, generating a not fully random but somewhat shuffled set within a range.   Similar to @sturgemeister code above, but not chunked.... there are no defined randomness boundaries.

For example:

```
def scramble(gen, buffer_size):
    buf = []
    i = iter(gen)
    while True:
        try:
            e = next(i)
            buf.append(e)
            if len(buf) >= buffer_size:
                choice = random.randint(0, len(buf)-1)
                buf[-1],buf[choice] = buf[choice],buf[-1]
                yield buf.pop()
        except StopIteration:
            random.shuffle(buf)
            yield from buf
            return
```

The results should be fully random within the `buffer_size` window:

```
for e in scramble(itertools.count(start=0, step=1), 1000):
    print(e)
```

For an arbitrary 1000 elements in this stream... they are random seeming.   But looking at  the overall trend (beyond 1000), it's clearly increasing.

To test, assert that this returns 1000 unique elements:

```
for e in scramble(range(1000), 100):
    print(e)
```

Comment: Nice implementation and decent performance, in my tests around 10X slower than iterating over a standard list() object. I also wasn't aware of the functionality of `yield from`, interesting!

Answer (score 2):

I needed to find a solution to this problem so I could get expensive to compute elements in a shuffled order, without wasting computation by generating values. This is what I have come up with for your example. It involves making another function to index the first array.

You will need numpy installed

```
pip install numpy
```

The Code:

```
import numpy as np
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

def shuffle_generator(lst):
    return (lst[idx] for idx in np.random.permutation(len(lst)))

def yielding(ls):
    for i in ls:
        yield i

# for i in random.shuffle(yielding(x)):
#    print i

for i in yielding(shuffle_generator(x)):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

For very large sequences, if you know the sequence size in advance:

```
class subset_iterator:
    """
    an iterator class that returns K random samples from another sequence
    that has no random-access. Requires: the sequence length as input

    similar to random.sample

    :param it: iterator to the sequence
    :param seqlen: size of the sequence of :param it:
    :param K: output sequence size (number of samples in the subset)
    """

    def __init__(self, it, seqlen, K):
        self.it = it
        self.N = seqlen
        self.K = K

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        while True:
            r = random()
            nextitem = next(self.it)
            if r <= float(self.K) / self.N:
                self.K -= 1
                self.N -= 1
                return nextitem
            else:
                self.N -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A generator follows a sequential access pattern. Shuffled data requires the exact opposite, a random access pattern.

In many applications, we can get away with local perturbations only, which relaxes the problem quite a lot.

Here is an example of an in memory shuffle buffer.

```
from random import randint
domain = (0, 1000)
buffer = [randint(*domain) for _ in range(50)]

for element in range(*domain):
    idx = randint(0, len(buffer)-1)
    element, buffer[idx] = buffer[idx], element
    print(element)
```